# set table cell value as default value on select2 box on clicking edit button in same row of cell?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-select2

This is my main page with h_register data table.

```
<table id="hreg" class="table table-hover table-bordered align-middle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Sr. No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Farmer</th>
            <th scope="col">Est. Bags</th>
            <th scope="col">Est. Wt.</th>
            <th scope="col">Actl. Bags</th>
            <th scope="col">Actl. Wt.</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $srno = 1;
            $curr_seasonId = $_SESSION['seasonId'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$currdb`.`hregister` WHERE `season_id` = '$curr_seasonId'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<tr>
                <td style='display:none'>".$row['id']."</td>
                <td>".$srno."</td>
                <td>".$row["date"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["farmer"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["est_bags"]."</td>
                <td>".(($row["est_bags"]*$row["kgs_bag"])/100)."</td>
                <td>".$row["actual_bags"]."</td>
                <td>".(($row["actual_bags"]*$row["kgs_bag"])/100)."</td>
                <td>".$row["actual_bags"]."</td>
                <td><button class='edit btn  btn-sm btn-primary' style='float: left;' id=" . $row['id'] . "> Edit</button>
                    <form action='' style='float: left;' class='ms-1' method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='delete' value='" . $row['id'] . "' />
                    <button type='submit' ms-1 class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' id='" . $row['id'] . "' >Delete</button></form></td>
                </tr>";
                $srno++;
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

code for edit data modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edithreg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitleId">Edit Heap Entry</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-cl>ose" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <label for="date_edit" class="form-label">Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="date_edit" name="date_edit">
                    <script>
                    $(function() {
                        $('input[name="hdate"]').daterangepicker({
                            singleDatePicker: true,
                            showDropdowns: true,
                            minYear: 1901,
                            autoApply: true,
                            locale: {
                                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                            }

                        })
                    });
                    </script>
                    <label for="farmer_name" class="form-label">Farmer</label>
                    <select class="form-select select2" aria-label="Default select example" id="farmer_name"
                        name="farmer_name" style="width: 100%" required>
                        <option value="" selected desabled>Select one</option>
                        <?php 
                                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$currdb`.`farmers`";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                        
                                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                                    echo'<option value="'.$row['name'].':'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <label for="est_bags" class="form-label">Est. Bags</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="est_bags" id="est_bags" aria-describedby="helpId"
                        placeholder="">
                    <label for="actl_bags" class="form-label">Actl. Bags</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="actl_bags" id="actl_bags" aria-describedby="helpId"
                        placeholder="">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script to trigger modal with values from table row which is being edited.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
edits = document.getElementsByClassName('edit')
Array.from(edits).forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        id_h = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText
        date_h = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerText
        farmer_h = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerText
        estbag_h = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[4].innerText
        actbag_h = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[6].innerText

        date_edit.value = date_h;
        farmer_name.value = farmer_h;
        est_bags.value = estbag_h;
        actl_bags.value = actbag_h;
       
        $('#edithreg').modal('toggle');
        $('#edithreg .select2').select2({
            // placeholder: farmer_h,
            // data:data,
                width: 'resolve',
            dropdownParent: $('#edithreg')
}).defaults.select2(farmer_h);
    })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.repeater').repeater({
        initEmpty: false, // it also could be true
        show: function() {
            $(this).slideDown(function() {
                $(this).find('.select2').select2({
                    placeholder: 'Select an option'
                });
            });
        },

        hide: function(deleteElement) {
            $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
        },

        ready: function(setIndexes) {
            // $('.select2').select2({
            //     placeholder: 'Select an option'
            // });
            $('#edithreg .select2').select2({
                width: 'resolve',
            dropdownParent: $('#edithreg')
});
        },
        isFirstItemUndeletable: false
    })
});
</script>
```

h_register data table output
[image]

edit data modal output
[image]

i am using select2 as select box.

My question is how can i set Farmer sell value (farmer name) to default select2 selected value?
For example: when someone click on edit button in 1st row, the farmer name :ANGREJ SINGH | KARAM SINGH | HAKAM SINGH should be selected by default in edit data modal instead of Select One.

as i am new to coding please explain with example. Thank you.

Comment: SIMPLY pass the farmer value to the modal when you click the edit button, then set the selected value in the select box

Comment: Please check this link ```Preselecting options in an remotely-sourced (AJAX) Select2```.

Comment: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2

Comment: You can preselect by using ```trigger``` function.

Comment: @KenLee how? Can you explain?

Comment: @DavidF i tried, but it didn't work. Can you explain?

Comment: did you check the url I sent?

Comment: ```var studentSelect = $('#mySelect2');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/students/s/' + studentId
}).then(function (data) {
    // create the option and append to Select2
    var option = new Option(data.full_name, data.id, true, true);
    studentSelect.append(option).trigger('change');

    // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
    studentSelect.trigger({
        type: 'select2:select',
        params: {
            data: data
        }
    });
});```